# SQL Server XML Attribute Shredding

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm currently running SQL Server 2014 and need to shred out attributes/sub attributes from a provided XML string, creating columns for Age, Color, Seating, and Transmission Type:

```
DECLARE @XmlInput xml;
SELECT @XmlInput = '<Cars><Car Description="(Camry) {Age=2, Color=Blue, Seating=5, TransmissionType=Automatic}"/><Car Description="(Fusion) {Age=4, Color=Red, Seating=5, TransmissionType=Automatic}"/></Cars>';
SELECT x.y.value('(@Description)[1]','varchar(1000)') AS CarDescr FROM @XmlInput.nodes('/Cars/Car') AS x(y);
```

I verified with the sender that this is the only way they can send XML without large workarounds on their end so I am stuck with the given XML format.

Edits:
I am looking for a return data set with a column for age, a column for color, a color for seating, etc.

I am running on SQL Server version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR) (KB4057120) - 12.0.5214.6 (X64)   Jan  9 2018 15:03:12   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: )

Comment: Whats not working then? And what are your expected results?

Comment: I'm only getting the 2 nodes of "(Camry) {Age=2, Color= Blue, Seating=5..." in my result when I'm looking for one column for Age, another column for Color, etc.

Comment: [edit] any clarifications directly into your question... and make sure it will all make sense to someone not familiar with your systems/data.

Comment: @Jayrunner13, what is your SQL Server version?

Comment: This is barely XML to begin with -- stuffing all data in a roll-your-own text format in an attribute is, well, pretty lazy. The problem with this being "the only way they can do it" is that T-SQL is a horrible language for general string processing, especially so for versions prior to 2016 which lack even basic string splitting capability. Consider processing this format outside the DB if there's no support forthcoming from the data supplier. Otherwise, what you're getting is essentially hacks and kludges on your end on top of hacks and kludges on their end, and it'll be hard to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no answer on the SQL Server version. I am assuming it is SQL Server 2016 or later with JSON support.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @XmlInput XML = 
N'<Cars>
    <Car Description="(Camry) {Age=2, Color=Blue, Seating=5, TransmissionType=Automatic}"/>
    <Car Description="(Fusion) {Age=4, Color=Red, Seating=5, TransmissionType=Automatic}"/>
</Cars>';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
            c.value('(@Description)[1]','varchar(1000)')
            ,'{','{"')
            ,'}','"}')
            ,'=','":"')
            ,', ','", "') AS CarDescr 
    FROM @XmlInput.nodes('/Cars/Car') AS t(c)
), cte AS
(
    SELECT LEFT(CarDescr, CHARINDEX(SPACE(1), CarDescr) - 1) AS Model
        , RIGHT(CarDescr, LEN(CarDescr) - CHARINDEX(SPACE(1), CarDescr)) AS [json]
        , * 
    FROM rs
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(Model, 2, LEN(Model)-2) AS [Model]
    , JSON_VALUE([json], '$.Age') AS [Age]
    , JSON_VALUE([json], '$.Color') AS [Color]
    , JSON_VALUE([json], '$.Seating') AS [Seating]
    , JSON_VALUE([json], '$.TransmissionType') AS [TransmissionType]
    , cte.json
FROM cte;
```

> Output

```
+--------+-----+-------+---------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Model  | Age | Color | Seating | TransmissionType |                                    json                                    |
+--------+-----+-------+---------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Camry  |   2 | Blue  |       5 | Automatic        | {"Age":"2", "Color":"Blue", "Seating":"5", "TransmissionType":"Automatic"} |
| Fusion |   4 | Red   |       5 | Automatic        | {"Age":"4", "Color":"Red", "Seating":"5", "TransmissionType":"Automatic"}  |
+--------+-----+-------+---------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```